# VIM: Replace line based of context on the next line

Tags: vim

I have a bunch of files and each mostly look like this:

```
...
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
...
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: ConfigMap
...
apiVersion: v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
...
     apiVersion: "v1"
     kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"
...
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
...
```

I would like to replace `apiVersion: v1` by `apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1` but only if the line below matches `kind: DeploymentConfig`.

Is there any way to do it with native vim functionality?

For security reasons I am not able to install any vim-plugins on that specific server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Do something on each line matching XXX" is the ideal use case for `:help :global`:

```
:g/kind: DeploymentConfig/-s/v1/apps.openshift.io\/&/c
```

where:

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on each line matching `<pattern>`,
- `kind: DeploymentConfig` is our `<pattern>` and the rest is our `<command>`,
- `-` is the address for `:help :s`, meaning "the line above",
- `s/v1/apps.openshift.io\/&` substitutes `v1` with `apps.openshift.io/v1` (see `:h :s/\&`),
- the `/c` at the end is a flag that tells Vim to prompt for confirmation for each substitution, it is facultative.

Comment: The solution is nice, but in this particular case there's a collision with the character `/` in the replacement string. Easily fixed by using some non-colliding character, e.g.:
`:g/kind: DeploymentConfig/-s_v1_apps.openshift.io/&_c`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use macro.

```
# start recording macro a
qa
# start searching
/kind: ConfigMap
# move up
k
# do replace
:.s/apiVersion: v1/apiVersion: apps.openshift.io\/v1/
# move down
j
# finish record
q
```

Then you can run `n@a` with number n to replace n times.

Comment: Thanks, I opend all my files using vi * and then run the macro on all files using :argdo norm 1000@a.

Comment: @Amit if you want to run it on each occurence, you can adopt the macro to call it self before finish it (so the last line would be `@aq` instead of just `q`.

Answer (score 2):

There are already two good suggestions, but here's a third method: You can match the next line in the `:substitute` pattern. The basic search-and-replace might look like this:

```
:%s/apiVersion: v1/apiVersion: v2/g
```

If you want to say "and the next line matches something particular", you can end the targeted pattern with `\ze` and then add `\_s\+` to indicate "any whitespace, including a newline":

```
:%s/apiVersion: v1\ze\_s\+kind: DeploymentConfig/apiVersion: v2/g
```

The `\zs` and `\ze` patterns are great for ad-hoc matches like this. You can also substitute only `v1` in this context by `v2` by anchoring the beginning with `\zs`:

```
:%s/apiVersion: \zsv1\ze\_s\+kind: DeploymentConfig/v2/g
```